# Easy Slider jQuery Plugin Centering Numberic Buttons With CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, centering

Hey there guys!
I am trying to implement [Easy Slider jQuery Plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) Version 1.7 and am having some issues.
From this [demo](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html) page, you can see the numbered buttons below the slide and I am trying to center that with the slide and just can't get it to work.

This is the default css for the numbered buttons and was wondering what I had to change it so that it centers within the page.

```
    /* numeric controls */  

ol#controls{
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
    height:28px;    
    }
ol#controls li{
    margin:0 10px 0 0; 
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;
    }
ol#controls li a{
    float:left;
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#DAF3F8;
    color:#555;
    padding:0 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
ol#controls li.current a{
    background:#5DC9E1;
    color:#fff;
    }
ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}
```

/* // Easy Slider */

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set

```
  text-align:center;
```

on the parent element.

Edit: add the following (with the correct width, I didn't check) to ol#controls style def:

```
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: the parent element would be #slider where the slide is cluded but centering that doesn't work

Comment: try applying it to the ol, #slider doesn't appear to contain the list.

Comment: i'll put it in a fiddle, give me a couple minutes (eating dinner real quick)

Comment: haha, having a hell of a hard time with it - you can float the ol left to get it to have the appropriate width, but that doesn't help matters. you can set a static width to the OL and then margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; This will work, but takes away some flexibility.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to figure it out! let me try it out

Comment: actually, if you can post the css that is working for you, it would be really helpful

Comment: for sure, you just have to find the correct width for the number of elements you have sliding. I'll post the working css in a sec.

Comment: appended the CSS I used to the answer.

Comment: Let me know if it isn't working, I may be missing a property somewhere.

Comment: i actually just used what u had specified for width, which is 250 and it seems to work perfectly! really appreciate it thanks :)

Comment: No problem, mind accepting if it is working? :) Oh, awesome. Thanks much , and  Thanks for your patience, sorry I failed for so long.